# Is a call to PDOStatement::closeCursor() necessary if the statement object is unset anway?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm utilizing a Mysql based *PDO connection* with **PDOStatement** (`::prepare()`; `::execute()`) and I've run over some code from a previous developer that utilizes [`PDOStatement::closeCursor()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.closecursor) in a method.

The statement is unset at the end of the function anyway:

```
public function fooBar($identifier)
{
    ...
    /** @var $dbc PDO */
    $dbc      = $conn->getConnection();
    $stmt     = $dbc->prepare('SELECT orderType, orderComment, payload FROM cart WHERE identifier = :identifier');
    $stmt->execute(array('identifier' => $identifier));

    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cart = $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    ...

    return $result;
}
```

In my mental model, I'd say that the PDOStatement is cleared here anyway, as I exepect the object to take care of this housekeeping (encapsulation basics). Therefore calling `PDOStatement::closeCursor()` looks supferfluous to me, especially, as this might not be exactly what is wanted here: As the statement is not to be re-used, I don't need to close the cursor at all.

> *side-note:* this code is exemplary, in the real code, there is even an exception thrown after `$stmt->execute(...)` if the row-count is not one (1).

### Existing Material on Stackoverflow

[Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168868/charles) [commmented back in May 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084396/pdo-free-result#comment7073753_6084479) in the question [pdo free result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6084396/367456):

> Not *just* some drivers -- some *settings* provided by drivers require closing the result set before firing off another query, like turning off MySQL's `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`. Thankfully you can call `closeCursor` and it will successfully do nothing when it doesn't need to take action.  Otherwise simply unsetting the variable containing the statement handle will clean up.

Another question [When should I use closeCursor() for PDO statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12843886/367456) has no accepted answer which I don't wonder about because it's all wishy-washy.

In *[Reusing PDO statement var crashes the process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16903290/367456)* there is [a comment made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903290/reusing-pdo-statement-var-crashes-the-process#comment30183672_20230375) that unsetting a variable does not get all errors (memory corruption bugs) out of the way:

> [...] I did try to unset the statement var before reassigning it but it didn't help. [...]

However I don't know if this is also true for local variables whose scope is to be gone. I also don't use `mod_php` as SAPI.

### Related Bug Material

- [Bug #66878   Multiple rowsets not returned unless PDO statement object is unset()](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66878)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`pdo_mysql_stmt_dtor()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c#pdo_mysql_stmt_dtor) runs the same cleanup operations as [`pdo_mysql_stmt_cursor_closer()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c#pdo_mysql_stmt_cursor_closer), so as long as the statement object is either explicitly unset or goes out of scope, the operations will always be performed.

It is therefore not strictly necessary to call `closeCursor()` if the statement is about to be destroyed anyway. Personally I would do it anyway as I like to be explicit for readability, but that comes down to personal stylistic preferences.

Based on the references above, this can *only* be said for certain about PDO_mysql - for other drivers this may not hold true.

Comment: Thanks to @bwoebi [feedback in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17526064#17526064) and also in *"[How does PHP's 'unset' construct work internally?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24557958/367456)"* it's now clear to me that `unset` calls the destructor, always. This is independent to garbage collection. [`unset` is called implicitly when the scope leaves the function](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17523775#17523775). This combined with your answer covers my case 100%. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of `PDOStatement::closeCursor()` is that it clears the result of a executed query. But not affects a `PDOStatement` at all (just the result of its execution).

[From the PHP Documnetation about this method](https://www.php.net/pdostatement.closecursor):

> frees up the connection to the server so that other SQL statements may
> be issued

and

> This method is useful for database drivers that do not support
> executing a PDOStatement object when a previously executed PDOStatement object still has unfetched rows.

let me assume that you should make after every execution and fetch of all data you need form the current query execution a call to the `PDOStatement::closeCursor()` method. I think the MySQL driver for PDO does this automatically but there seems to be problems with some drivers which does not automatically free up the result.

So if you switch to another DB driver which does not free up the pending result of the query you run into an error.